# Minimal edge-to-edge euclidean distance between labeled components in numpy array

Tags: numpy, image-processing, scipy, euclidean-distance, connected-components

I have a number of distinct forms in large `numpy` arrays and I want to calculate the edge-to-edge euclidean distance between them using `numpy` and `scipy`.

**Note**: I did a search and this is different from previous other questions here on stack as I want to obtain the smallest distance between labeled patches within an array and not between points or seperate arrays as other questions have asked.

My current approach works using a KDTree, but is horribly inefficient for large arrays. Essentially I am looking up the coordinates of each labeled component and calculate the distance between all other components. Finally the average minimal distance is calculated as an example.

I am looking for a smarter approach using python and preferably without any extra modules.

```
import numpy
from scipy import spatial
from scipy import ndimage

# Testing array
a = numpy.zeros((8,8), dtype=numpy.int)
a[2,2] = a[3,1] = a[3,2] = 1
a[2,6] = a[2,7] = a[1,6] = 1
a[5,5] = a[5,6] = a[6,5] = a[6,6] = a[7,5] = a[7,6] = 1    

# label it
labeled_array,numpatches = ndimage.label(a)

# For number of patches
closest_points = []
for patch in [x+1 for x in range(numpatches)]:
# Get coordinates of first patch
    x,y = numpy.where(labeled_array==patch)
    coords = numpy.vstack((x,y)).T # transform into array
    # Built a KDtree of the coords of the first patch
    mt = spatial.cKDTree(coords)

    for patch2 in [i+1 for i in range(numpatches)]:
        if patch == patch2: # If patch is the same as the first, skip
            continue
        # Get coordinates of second patch
        x2,y2 = numpy.where(labeled_array==patch2)
        coords2 = numpy.vstack((x2,y2)).T

        # Now loop through points
        min_res = []
        for pi in range(len(coords2)):
            dist, indexes = mt.query(coords2[pi]) # query the distance and index
            min_res.append([dist,pi])
        m = numpy.vstack(min_res)
        # Find minimum as closed point and get index of coordinates
        closest_points.append( coords2[m[numpy.argmin(m,axis=0)[0]][1]] )


# The average euclidean distance can then be calculated like this:
spatial.distance.pdist(closest_points,metric = "euclidean").mean()
```

---

**EDIT**
Just tested @morningsun proposed solution and it is a huge speed improvement. However the values returned are slightly different:

```
# Consider for instance the following array
a = numpy.zeros((8,8), dtype=numpy.int)
a[2,2] = a[2,6] = a[5,5] = 1  

labeled_array, numpatches = ndimage.label(cl_array,s)

# Previous approach using KDtrees and pdist
b = kd(labeled_array,numpatches)
spatial.distance.pdist(b,metric = "euclidean").mean()
#> 3.0413115592767102

# New approach using the lower matrix and selecting only lower distances
b = numpy.tril( feature_dist(labeled_array) )
b[b == 0 ] = numpy.nan
numpy.nanmean(b)
#> 3.8016394490958878
```

**EDIT 2**

Ah, figured it out. spatial.distance.pdist does not return a proper distance matrix and thus the values were wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a fully vectorized way to find the distance matrix for the labeled objects:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

def feature_dist(input):
    """
    Takes a labeled array as returned by scipy.ndimage.label and 
    returns an intra-feature distance matrix.
    """
    I, J = np.nonzero(input)
    labels = input[I,J]
    coords = np.column_stack((I,J))

    sorter = np.argsort(labels)
    labels = labels[sorter]
    coords = coords[sorter]

    sq_dists = cdist(coords, coords, 'sqeuclidean')

    start_idx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[1, np.diff(labels)])
    nonzero_vs_feat = np.minimum.reduceat(sq_dists, start_idx, axis=1)
    feat_vs_feat = np.minimum.reduceat(nonzero_vs_feat, start_idx, axis=0)

    return np.sqrt(feat_vs_feat)
```

This approach requires O(N<sup>2</sup>) memory, where N is the number of nonzero pixels. If this is too demanding, you could "de-vectorize" it along one axis (add a for-loop).

Comment: Thanks you for this! I just tested it out on one of my datasets and it runs almost 89% faster. Power of vectorization. Although I don't fully understand why 'sqeuclidean' was computed. It also returns different values if attempt to calculate for instance the mean of all differences (See edit in question).

Comment: Ahh, figured it out (see above). Pdist does not return a proper distance matrix and thus my previous values were wrong... Thanks again for your solution!

Comment: @Curlew - The squared euclidean is faster to calculate. Note that I used it only for intermediate results; the square root is taken in the return statement.